# HP Photosmart C4500 wireless printer not appearing with networks

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-access-point, hp-photosmart

I Have an HP Photosmart C4500 series wireless all-in-one printer.

I'm trying to connect it to my Windows 8.1 64-bit PC which has a Gigabyte Bluetooth 4.0/WiFi Expansion Card (adapter) for wireless connectivity. Those printers usually appear as a wireless network named "hpsetup".

This network appears on other devices but it is not appearing on my PC. I don't think it is a printer driver problem because i'm not connected yet + other WiFi networks appear normally so I don't think it's the network driver.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have your logic reversed. Your printer doesn't appear on your PC. It's your printer that has to find your PC's wireless network.

You must connect your printer with hard line first to acclimate your printer to your pc. Then disconnect and use wireless setup.

The CD is most likely an instruction CD nothing more, but it describes this process I mention above.

Start here:

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/71239/Hp-Photosmart-C4500.html?page=15#manual

then click NEXT and it will give you complete instructions step by step starting with "A standard USB cable to connect temporarily for transferring wireless settings."

There is also another message on the NEXT page:

" Connect to an integrated wireless WLAN 802.11 network
The HP Photosmart Software CD and included USB setup cable provide an easy way toconnect the HP All-in-One to your wireless network. "

More on instructions in detail:
To connect the product

1.Insert the product Software CD in the computer CD-ROM drive.

2.Follow the instructions on the screen.When you are prompted, connect the product to the computer using the USB setupcable included in the box. The product will attempt to connect to the network. If theconnection fails, follow the prompts to correct the problem, and then try again.

3.When the setup is finished, you will be prompted to disconnect the USB cable andtest the wireless network connection. Once the product connects successfully to thenetwork, install the software on each computer that will use the product over thenetwork.

Comment: I know my logic is reversed because it actually is. The printer appears as a separate network connection named "hpsetup" (like a router on its own). You can connect directly to it and not by sharing a network. You should right your solution on that basis. However, The link you posted mentions this technique as "ad hoc network setup". That might help and I'll tell you once I try it.

Comment: @onlyforthis The link is a reference to the printer's actual HP PhotoSmart Manual. The ad-hok you refer to is listed in a "list of possible solutions" on desired setups for the user; it's a list of reasonable setup solutions and ad-hoc is one of many solutions.

Comment: @onlyforthis So, if you follow the link just as I laid it out that should do the trick. If you look closely it reads:If you want to: Connect to a wireless network with a wirelessrouter (infrastructure). Then click NEXT for this setup which is on the page (p.12). The ad-hoc you mention is on page 19. If you have a router, then this is the solution that you should use and the most secure. I used to own this printer, it should work for you right away if you follow the steps. I know how it is skim reading so no harm no foul. Good luck and I hope it works out easily!